# How to color everyother line in sublime text

Tags: syntax, color-scheme, sublimetext4

I'm currently trying to make a custom color scheme for sublime text for various uses. One of the things I really would like to have is an alternating colors for every other line in a list.
I want something that would look like :

*1. Item 1*

**2. Item 2**

*3. Item 3*

**4. Item 4**

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: You would have to make a custom syntax to support such highlighting. There is plenty of information to get you started in [the official docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html). However, let me warn you that this task is non-trivial.

Comment: Update : I got a thing working using color schemes and sublime 
syntax files! Thank you leading me the correct direction @MattDMo
You were correct it was non-trivial but it was fun to learn!